# scikit-learn's LabelEncoder() memory issue

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a `train` pandas df with 20 million rows and a `test` pandas df with around 10 million rows.

There are columns in both of the df's that I want to apply LabelEncoder() to, but I keep getting a `Memory Error` on my laptop and even on a 64 gig RAM AWS instance.

Is there a way I can deal with this in chunks without losing the mapping?

Here is the code I was using:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()

for col in cols_to_encode:
    le.fit(list(train[col])+list(test[col]))
    train[col] = le.transform(train[col])
    test[col] = le.transform(test[col])
```

I sampled 500,000 rows from each and was able to run the code with no error, so I know it's not a syntax error or something.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used LabelEncoder before, but from my work with Sklearn, I know that there are options that can help parallelize. Have you tried looking into parallelizing this task? Either using a parameter like n_jobs which many sklearn classifiers have, or even the python multiprocessing library.

Comment: The first thing I did was check for the `n_jobs` parameter, but it doesn't seem to exist for this function. Usually `n_jobs` is for classifiers, not helper functions.